# Is it possible to get a pointer to the instance of a react component from outside of its constructor?

Tags: reactjs

Consider this react component,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Frame extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('constructor', this)  // I want *this* but ...
  }

  render() {
    return <p></p>
  }
}

export default Frame
```

And we initialise it like so,

```
const view = <Frame />
console.log(view)  // here!
```

The two print statements print,

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
constructor Frame {props: {…}, context: undefined, refs: {…}, updater: {…}}
```

So, I essentially want the pointer `this` that is inside the constructor but at where I initialise frame via jsx to the variable `view`. Is that possible?

Comment: You shouldn't need that

Comment: @Konrad your comment was not helpful even if correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSX `<>` syntax is only synthetic sugar for `React.createElement(Component, props, ...children)`

Your class component gets initialized inside that function by react that never exposes the value of `this` so no way to get a pointer to it

Comment: Is there then any way to pass `this` to another function in that case? I guess I could simply pass `this` inside the constructor but that seems to pollute the constructor of frame IMHO.

Comment: yes that can be done by binding this to the method in the constuctor
this.yourMethod = this.yourMethod.bind(this);
That is outdated pattern and can most of the time be avoided see here 
https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#constructor